# Kubernetes NodePort traffic balance works weird

Tags: kubernetes

I have a cluster with 2 nodes:

- Controller
- Worker

I have created deployment, which creates 2 pods within the cluster. In my example it looks like:

- Pod1 -> Controller
- Pod2 -> Worker

Then I created a `NodePort` service, which should route the traffic in some specific way. I was hoping for

- 50% of the requests to be handled by Pod1
- 50% by Pod2

But unfortunately it does not work this way. It looks like when I request a resource, and I keep requesting (refreshing a page), Pod1 (in the example) is handling the requests. Then, when I wait a bit (i.e. 1 minute) without any requests, and after this time I request the resource Pod2 starts to answer (and again, when I keep refreshing, Pod2 is still handling it).

Is it correct behavior? How can I make NodePort to route trafic in real 50/50 in this case?

Thanks